# SSl certificate for Exchange 2010

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, exchange-2010, ssl-certificate, certificate

We are planning to migrate from exchange 2003 to exchange 2010. Currently we have a certificate for ex2003 issued by godaddy with 2 subject alternate names.

My question is can we use the same cert for exchange 2010 with exchange 2003 in co-existence ? And if yes how can we do this ?

Thanks

Comment: As long as you use one of the alternate names for the server name, you should be fine.  Are you just using the cert for OWA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason why a given certificate cant be used in multiple places.  We have, for example, a wildcard certificate for *.company.com and use it on a whole load of different Windows and Linux servers.

What is important is that the certificate name or any of the subject alternate names match the URL you are going to be using the certificate for.  And that in turn depends on how you will be doing your migration.